# Making a fixed table header for a table that has an unknown amount of rows and columns

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm making a MVC application, in which I get information from a database. There is no limitation to how many rows and columns a table can have and  the table placed somewhere in center, and the web application is responsive. Here is my table generating code:

```
@model Dto.Table
@{
    var model = ViewContext.ViewData.Model as Dto.BaseModel;
    if (!model.IsPartial)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PageMainLayout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = null;
    }
}

<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="table-hover" style="overflow-x:auto">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            <th>@item</th>
                        }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach(var row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach(var columnValue in row.Values)
                        {
                            <td>@columnValue</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>

        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I have added some css witch was suggested:

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: auto;
}

thead {
    background: #1ABC9C;
    color: white;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px 0;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

thead, tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And this is how it looks 
[image]

Comment: You have Used  Col-md-12

Comment: n-rows means you are planning to go for page scrolling or table scrolling?

Comment: @Prabhakaran page scrolling, but I might chabge it to table scrolling

Answer (score 2):

I added dummy data. Hope it helps if you are going for table scroll

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

thead{
  background:#1ABC9C;
   color:white;
}

th,td{
   padding:5px 0;
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

thead, tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead class="fixed">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your comment gives, what I need, for witch I'm thankful, however sometimes there is too much data and the table get distorted. Look at my post for picture

Comment: add a emptydiv at the end of header of width around 15px(width of scroll bar.). This distortion occurs because of scroll bar. Also carefull if less data than the table height remove the empty div or style your scrollbar. From your coding it seems you are using Bootstrap, check for possible solution in any bootstrap forum

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Yes, I'm using bootstrap, but I haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 0):

You have Responsive Center of the table used to span class in twitter bootstrap.In case using bootstrap then using col-md(col-Md-1 to 12)

for Example :

```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="span4"></div>
       <div class="span4">
        <table> your table</table>
      </div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Setting the table in the middle isn't the problem